# Rust tracing/opentelemetry adding context attributes dynamically

Tags: rust, open-telemetry, actix-web, rust-tracing

I have a Rust app that is using tracing + OpenTelemetry.
I would like to be able to dynamically set key/value pairs that I can use in a custom `tracing::Subscriber` layer. In Java, this is usually accomplished with [MDC](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html).

In Rust, I have tried setting attributes on the [`opentelemetry::Context`](https://docs.rs/opentelemetry/latest/opentelemetry/struct.Context.html) following the documentation but when I try to access it in my subscriber, its `None`.

I have also tried setting attributes using `tracing::span!(..., foo=bar)` however this does not appear to allow dynamically adding attributes.

Here is my current tracing/otel config

```rs
 let tracer = opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
        .tracing()
        .with_exporter(opentelemetry_otlp::new_exporter().tonic())
        .install_batch(opentelemetry_sdk::runtime::AsyncStd)
        .unwrap();
    let telemetry = OpenTelemetryLayer::new(tracer);
    let custom_layer = create_custom_layer();

    tracing_subscriber::registry()
        .with(telemetry)
        .with(custom_layer)
        .init();
```

Comment: `tracing` is designed for statically determined fields, for maximum efficiency. What prevents you from adding an `extra: &[(String, &dyn Debug)]` or something like that?

Comment: would you mind providing an example?